# select date with increment range in google analytics use javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I'm creating an scripts that need to choose date with a increment range in Google analytics.

eg:

user choose 1st March as start, and 30th May as end, and set an increment range 3.

The script will choose 1st March as start, and 3rd March as end and apply.

Then Choose 4th March as start and 6th March as end, and apply.

...

I know how to do this with in 1 month but I don't know how to handle  multiple month, such as, choose 30th March as start, then need to choose 1st April as end.

select within 1 month code like this:

```
function selectDate() {
    var dateTD = $("td._GAb-_GAz-_GAH-_GAz");// the day selector
    $("#ID-reportHeader-dateControl").find("._GAFN").click();
    dateTD.filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == startDate.toString(); //startDate is save start number
    }).click();
    var theEnd;
    if ((startDate + dateRage - 1) > endDate) {
        theEnd = endDate;
    } else {
        theEnd = startDate + dateRage - 1; //dateRang: the increament rage
    }
    var endTD = dateTD.filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == theEnd.toString();
    });
    startDate += dateRage;
    endTD.click();
    $("input[type='button'][value='Apply']").click(); // apply button in GA date picker
    sleep(15); // wait for 15 sec after aplly
    if (startDate < endDate) {
        selectDate();
    }

}
```

[image: GA datepacker]

Comment: What's the code look like for the 1 month?

Comment: @Blexy  I added the sample code